# problem while switching between Portrait and landscape in android views

Tags: android, view

In my application im going to display a web page in web view , it works fine but if i flip between landscape to portrait or vice versa, then it exits and comes to main page. wht is the prblm?

logcat:

```
03-10 13:35:47.123: INFO/WindowManager(69): Setting rotation to 1, animFlags=1
03-10 13:35:47.242: INFO/ActivityManager(69): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/1 nav=3/1 orien=2 layout=17 uiMode=17 seq=70}
03-10 13:35:47.363: INFO/UsageStats(69): Unexpected resume of com.mireader while already resumed in com.mireader
03-10 13:35:50.413: DEBUG/dalvikvm(69): GC_EXPLICIT freed 395 objects / 20424 bytes in 195ms
```

Comment: What does the stack trace says?

Comment: @Mudassir qust edited...

Comment: Is that all. Exception details are not there.

Comment: That one, Android is throwing.

Comment: @Mudassir No exception is thrown other than logcat i displayed

Comment: Without the exception details, I am unable to figure out the problem. Check if you are not missing anything.

Comment: @Mudassir 03-10 14:51:17.233: WARN/PhoneWindow(22222): Previously focused view reported id 2131034117 during save, but can't be found during restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the device orientation is changing, the activity is destroyed then recreated.

This also leads the activity's contentview to be recreated.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges for more details.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html "....it is sometimes confusing for new Android developers, who wonder why their activity is destroyed and recreated".

Comment: Yes all other platforms do not behave that way. However it is possible to handle the configuration change yourself.

Comment: @vnshetty See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android) for this.